# Make a animated transition like this in material nodes

Tags: materials, transparency, shader-nodes

## I want to make a transition effect like this

[image]

***Made with windows movie maker***

*excuse the poor choice of images as an example.*

---

#### I've tried *gradient texture* but can only slide it on one side, So far I have this

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can be something like this:

[image]

Get the X component of generated coordinates (or UV), recenter it between -1 and 1, then absolute to have symmetrical value.

Then animate (keyframe) the "greater than" math node and plug it as factor in a mix color node (using colors, or images as you like).